# How to disable button by selecting comboBox value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a comoboBox that is binded to sql database, and I added a default text at index 0 like this

```
string s = "< -------------Select an application ----------->";
applicationComboBox.Items.Insert(0, s);
applicationComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I am wondering if there is a way to disable my button if the the string s at index 0 is select? In my comboBox, I binded the data with the `while(SQLReader.Read()) method instead of using ValueMember` and `DisplayMember

Here is what I tried but no luck

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < applicationComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string value = applicationComboBox.GetItemText(applicationComboBox.Items[0]);

            string s = "<------------- Select an application ----------->";

            if (value == s)
            {
                exportButton.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show(value); //nothing happen
                this.teacherCheckListBox.DataSource = null;
                teacherCheckListBox.Items.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                exportButton.Enabled = true;   
            }                  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to diable the button? On selection changed event or default?

Comment: on the select change event. Because I don't want the use to be able to do anything if they didn't select a application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectedIndex` property to know which item is selected and disable the button if it is first item.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        exportButton.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```